# jQuery UI autocomplete with ajax which source is generated from text file using foreach

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, foreach, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I did a lot of searching and I got a lot of results similar to my case, listed below:

- [Jquery UI autocomplete ajax is not populating dropdown box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481972/jquery-ui-autocomplete-ajax-is-not-populating-dropdown-box)
- [jQuery UI GET autocomplete source with ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619184/jquery-ui-get-autocomplete-source-with-ajax-request)
- [JQuery UI autocomplete with json and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852282/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-and-ajax)

Data source is from text file which format like this:

```
postcode,suburb,state,lat,lon
200,AUSTRALIAN NATIONAL UNIVERSITY,ACT,-35.277272,149.117136
221,BARTON,ACT,-35.201372,149.095065
800,DARWIN,NT,-12.801028,130.955789
801,DARWIN,NT,-12.801028,130.955789
804,PARAP,NT,-12.432181,130.84331
810,ALAWA,NT,-12.378451,130.877014
810,BRINKIN,NT,-12.367769,130.869808
810,CASUARINA,NT,-12.376597,130.850489
810,JINGILI,NT,-12.385761,130.873726
810,LEE POINT,NT,-12.360865,130.891349
```

The data I'm trying to include as source of auto-complete field is the first and second(postcode and suburb) fields of each row. But the postcode and suburb filter with state. For example ACT is the active state all the postcode and suburb is the source of auto-complete. And I used `array_unique()` to remove the repeated data.

```
//take area from state
function take_area(){
    global $wpdb;
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload = $uploads[baseurl];
    $file = $upload.'/csv/suburb_and_area.txt';
    $f = fopen($file, 'r');
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $counter = 0;
    while($line = fgets($f, 4096)){
        $details = explode(',', $line); 
        $counter++;
        if(trim($details[2]) == $state){
            $state_arr[$counter] = $details[1];
        }
    }
    $option = '';
    if($state!=''){
        $c=0;
        $area_of_state = array_unique($state_arr);
        foreach($area_of_state as $area){
            if($c>0){$option .= ', ';}
            $option .= '"'.$area.'"';
            $c++;
        }
    }
    echo $option;
}
```

and the JavaScript:

```
    $("#state").change(function(){
    var state = $('#state :selected').attr('data-value');
    if(!state){
        state = $('#state').val();
    }
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
        type:'POST',
        data:'action=take_area_from_state&state=' + state,
        success:function(results){
            if(results!=0){
                $("#area").removeAttr("disabled"); 
                $("#area").empty();
                var source = [results];
                $("#area").autocomplete({source: source});
            }else{
                $("#area").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
            }
        }
    });

});
```

And the Response

```
"AUSTRALIAN NATIONAL UNIVERSITY", "BARTON", "HMAS CRESWELL", "JERVIS BAY", "CANBERRA", "DEAKIN", "DEAKIN WEST", "DUNTROON", "HARMAN", "HMAS HARMAN", "PARKES", "PARLIAMENT HOUSE", "RUSSELL", "YARRALUMLA", "ACTON", "BLACK MOUNTAIN", "AINSLIE", "DICKSON", "DOWNER", "HACKETT", "LYNEHAM", "O'CONNOR", "WATSON", "FORREST", "GRIFFITH", "MANUKA", "RED HILL", "CAUSEWAY", "KINGSTON", "NARRABUNDAH", "CURTIN", "GARRAN", "HUGHES", "CHIFLEY", "LYONS", "O'MALLEY", "PHILLIP", "SWINGER HILL", "WODEN", "FARRER", "ISAACS", "MAWSON", "PEARCE", "TORRENS", "CIVIC SQUARE", "CANBERRA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT", "FYSHWICK", "MAJURA", "PIALLIGO", "SYMONSTON", "CHAPMAN", "DUFFY", "FISHER", "HOLDER", "MOUNT STROMLO", "PIERCES CREEK", "RIVETT", "STIRLING", "URIARRA", "URIARRA FOREST", "WARAMANGA", "WESTON", "WESTON CREEK", "BRADDON", "CAMPBELL", "REID", "TURNER", "ARANDA", "COOK", "HAWKER", "JAMISON CENTRE", "MACQUARIE", "PAGE", "SCULLIN", "WEETANGERA", "CHARNWOOD", "DUNLOP", "FLOREY", "FLYNN", "FRASER", "HIGGINS", "HOLT", "KIPPAX", "LATHAM", "MACGREGOR", "MELBA", "SPENCE", "BELCONNEN", "BRUCE", "EVATT", "GIRALANG", "KALEEN", "LAWSON", "MCKELLAR", "UNIVERSITY OF CANBERRA", "HALL", "HUME", "KOWEN FOREST", "OAKS ESTATE", "THARWA", "TOP NAAS", "GREENWAY", "TUGGERANONG", "KAMBAH", "ERINDALE CENTRE", "OXLEY", "WANNIASSA", "FADDEN", "GOWRIE", "MACARTHUR", "MONASH", "BONYTHON", "CALWELL", "CHISHOLM", "GILMORE", "ISABELLA PLAINS", "RICHARDSON", "THEODORE", "BANKS", "CONDER", "GORDON", "CRACE", "MITCHELL", "GUNGAHLIN", "FRANKLIN", "GINNINDERRA VILLAGE", "NGUNNAWAL", "NICHOLLS", "PALMERSTON", "AMAROO", "BONNER", "FORDE", "HARRISON"
```

The data is displayed like this:
[image]

I know I've done wrong to my code but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you try `$("#area").autocomplete({ source: results })`?

Comment: Can you show the response you're getting from the server?

Comment: Are you using Firebug? Or Chrome's developer tools? You can view the response in Firebug's console or in the net tab in Chrome.

Comment: by that way sir the code `$("#area").autocomplete({ source: results })` that is not display anything. I fail to clear my browser cache.

Comment: That looks like you aren't referencing the jquery.ui style sheet.

Comment: I didn't mean the HTML, I mean the response you get from the server after making a request. What does that look like?

Comment: my question is update with response.

Comment: Whether the response coming as an text or an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use something like

$(function(){

```
var src = [];

$('#area').autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        response(src)
    }
});

$("#state").change(function(){
    var state = $('#state :selected').attr('data-value');
    if(!state){
        state = $('#state').val();
    }
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
        type:'POST',
        data:'action=take_area_from_state&state=' + state,
        success:function(results){
            if(results!=0){
                $("#area").removeAttr("disabled"); 
                src = $.map(results.split(','), function(v, i){ <----- Convert the string result into an array of objects
                    return {
                        label: v,
                        varlue: v
                    };
                });
            }else{
                $("#area").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
            }
        }
    });

});
```

});

Again I'm not sure about your response data from the server. The `result` object in the `success` callback should be array of objects like `[{label: '<text-to-appear-in-the-dropdown>', value: '<value>'}, {...}, {...}, ...]`

Technical Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEHne/) (It doesn't uses ajax based source)

If your ajax query is returning an array, then you can create the src array as given below.

```
var result = ["AUSTRALIAN NATIONAL UNIVERSITY", "BARTON", "HMAS CRESWELL", "JERVIS BAY", "CANBERRA", "DEAKIN", "DEAKIN WEST", "DUNTROON", "HARMAN", "HMAS HARMAN", "PARKES", "PARLIAMENT HOUSE", "RUSSELL", "YARRALUMLA", "ACTON", "BLACK MOUNTAIN", "AINSLIE", "DICKSON", "DOWNER", "HACKETT", "LYNEHAM", "O'CONNOR", "WATSON", "FORREST", "GRIFFITH", "MANUKA", "RED HILL", "CAUSEWAY", "KINGSTON", "NARRABUNDAH", "CURTIN", "GARRAN", "HUGHES", "CHIFLEY", "LYONS", "O'MALLEY", "PHILLIP", "SWINGER HILL", "WODEN", "FARRER", "ISAACS", "MAWSON", "PEARCE", "TORRENS", "CIVIC SQUARE", "CANBERRA INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT", "FYSHWICK", "MAJURA", "PIALLIGO", "SYMONSTON", "CHAPMAN", "DUFFY", "FISHER", "HOLDER", "MOUNT STROMLO", "PIERCES CREEK", "RIVETT", "STIRLING", "URIARRA", "URIARRA FOREST", "WARAMANGA", "WESTON", "WESTON CREEK", "BRADDON", "CAMPBELL", "REID", "TURNER", "ARANDA", "COOK", "HAWKER", "JAMISON CENTRE", "MACQUARIE", "PAGE", "SCULLIN", "WEETANGERA", "CHARNWOOD", "DUNLOP", "FLOREY", "FLYNN", "FRASER", "HIGGINS", "HOLT", "KIPPAX", "LATHAM", "MACGREGOR", "MELBA", "SPENCE", "BELCONNEN", "BRUCE", "EVATT", "GIRALANG", "KALEEN", "LAWSON", "MCKELLAR", "UNIVERSITY OF CANBERRA", "HALL", "HUME", "KOWEN FOREST", "OAKS ESTATE", "THARWA", "TOP NAAS", "GREENWAY", "TUGGERANONG", "KAMBAH", "ERINDALE CENTRE", "OXLEY", "WANNIASSA", "FADDEN", "GOWRIE", "MACARTHUR", "MONASH", "BONYTHON", "CALWELL", "CHISHOLM", "GILMORE", "ISABELLA PLAINS", "RICHARDSON", "THEODORE", "BANKS", "CONDER", "GORDON", "CRACE", "MITCHELL", "GUNGAHLIN", "FRANKLIN", "GINNINDERRA VILLAGE", "NGUNNAWAL", "NICHOLLS", "PALMERSTON", "AMAROO", "BONNER", "FORDE", "HARRISON"]

src = $.map(result, function(val){
    return {label: val, value: val};
});
```

[Another sample](http://jsfiddle.net/DEHne/1/) with query param support

Comment: thanks for answer, I try this before to `response(src)` and the source display per letter like
`"
A
S` and so on.

Comment: Can you following the below steps and let us know the results. In the ajax callback `success:function(results){` add two statements `console.log(result);` and `console.log(typeof result)`. Then check the console to see the output.

Comment: There are two in Console: `"AUSTRALIAN NATIONAL UNIVERSITY", "NICHOLLS", "PALMERSTON", "AMAROO", "BONNER", "FORDE", "HARRISON"` and `string`.

Comment: that is the problem, the response is of type `string` not `array`.

Comment: is the double quotes present around each item

Comment: @jho1086 I've updated the answer, In the ajax success callback I've made some changes

Comment: Why is the response is not filtering like the default autocomplete field. When I type 'C' its typically display all item has 'C'. For now it is displayed all the data. I can't filter it like other question because they are querying from database and they use LIKE %, something like that.

Comment: @jho1086 At the bottom of the answer there is a link to a fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/DEHne/1/ ), where it is handled. But looks like jsfiddle is down for now